# using MsDeploy-Sync to copy only one file locally

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Currently i am copying all the `$DeploymentPath` (folder) locally, and then 
deleting all the files in it, except 1 file that i want.

```
MsDeploy-Sync `
       -SourceContentPath:"$DeploymentPath" `
       -DestinationContentPath:"$SupportFolder/WebPages" `

Get-ChildItem "$SupportFolder\WebPages" -Exclude "web.config.js" |
  Remove-Item
```

What i want to do:

copy only 1 file `web.config.js` locally, if it doesn't exist there, return false.

- i am writing this piece of code in `ps1` file, but i have to use `MsDeploy` commands.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use the [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet to combine a path in PowerShell.

To check whether the file exist, just use the [Test-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113418) cmdlet:

```
$webConfigPath = Join-Path $SupportFolder '\WebPages\web.config.js'
if (Test-Path $webConfigPath)
{
     MsDeploy-Sync `
        -SourceContentPath (Join-Path $DeploymentPath 'web.config.js') `
        -DestinationContentPath (Join-Path $SupportFolder 'fromServer_web.config.js')
}
else
{
    $false # return $false
}
```

Comment: i used  MsDeploy-Sync `
        -SourceContentPath:"$DeploymentPath\web.config.js" `
        -DestinationContentPath:"$SupportFolder/fromServer_web.config.js" `
to copy the one file that i need from server, please add this, inside the `if`

Comment: I added it and also using the Join-Path cmdlet there.

Comment: why do you prefer to use `Join-Path` instead of regular path?

Comment: Because joining a path using string interpolation is error prone. For example: If you join `$DeploymentPath` with 'web.config.js' and it doesn't contain a trailing backslash, you will get a wrong path. If you use the `Join-Path` cmdlet, you don't have to worry about trailing backslashes...